# Hosting options to deploy small entrepreneurship NextJS App

Tags: deployment, hosting, web-deployment, web-hosting, vercel

I've developed my first real App with NextJS and Im about to deploy it. The problem is that being a REAL App maybe it may have a custom domain so I'll have to deploy it with Hostinger for example. The app is FullStack but pretty simple and small and it won't be very visited so maybe buying a domain is not gonna be that necesary.
So my question is, should I go with domain or isn't that bad if I deploy it with vercel like "APPNAME.vercel.app"? (Or any other free hosting option with those semi-custom domains)
Any tips?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends how you want to use your app.

If you have very limited users and if you're hosting it for just testing, it's okay to keep in on free domain like [APPNAME.vercel.app](https://APPNAME.vercel.app)

But, If you have a long-term plan and you have little experience of hosting full-stack app on free domain,
I recommend getting proper domain name with your custom URL.

You can get one those domain name in a good price. Many of those provider offers good deals on pricing. Some of them also offers first year free plan.

Let's say, you changed your mind after one year, you can discontinue hosting.

If you have very useful app concept in mind, you never know when your app will start getting popularity.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What you say is true, but I want to add that the app is about a small bakery entrepreneurship, that's why I wasnt that sure about hosting with a paid domain.
Thanks for ur time :D